# netcoreapp2.0 preview2. Identity configuration

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, postman

There is a problem with cookies configuration. In chrome everything works fine, but there are some problems with Postman. It doesn't define all the cookies. (Interceptor is on).

Here is my identity configuration

```
ConfigureServices()
{
    services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
    {
        auth.DefaultChallengeScheme =CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddCookieAuthentication(auth =>
    {
        auth.LoginPath = "/account/login";
        auth.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    }
}

Configure()
{
     app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

With netcoreapp1.1 and this configuration

```
Configure()
{
     app.UseIdentity();
}
ConfigureServices()
{
     services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
     {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout");
     }
}
```

everything works fine

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are only adding one cookie, what other cookies are you expecting?

Comment: @JoeAudette you are right, both Postman & Chrome are setting only .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie. I think there is some bug with identity. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/06/28/introducing-asp-net-core-2-0-preview-2/
NET Core Identity as a Service is in Postponed features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Postman (Desktop app only)
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3146